# Static resource array binding only works for the first time

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, wpf-controls, toolbar

I created a custom control which inherits from toolbar.

I would like that the default control template of the toolbar will contain a couple of default buttons.

In order to achieve this, I created a static array to hold the button list:

```
<x:Array x:Key="toolbarButtons" Type="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <ToggleButton Content="Bold" 
                      Command="{x:Static ns1:EditingCommands.Bold}"
                      CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsBold, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <ToggleButton Content="Italic" 
                      Command="{x:Static ns1:EditingCommands.Italic}"
                      CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsItalic, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</x:Array>
```

The toolbar control has datacontext which is bounded to a text editor which includes all of the command bindings and the boolean dependency properties (`IsBold`, `IsItalic`).

I set the Toolbar ItemSource to use the array like this:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource toolbarButtons}"/>
```

Now, when I open a window who hosts the toolbar for the first time on a given run, everything works great.

The problem is, when I close the window, and reopen it, the button bindings stop working (`IsCheked` property stops being connected to the dependency property).

I used snoop to check the bindings, and it says that the value of `IsChecked` is local, which means the binding is ignored.

I suspect that the problem is my array is a static resource, so the toolbar uses the same instance from time to time, and this somehow ruins the binding.

My question is how to solve this, or maybe should I use a different approach in order to achieve default buttons for my toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you declare your array in XAML, it's only instantiated once. So, the second toolbar (and on) are trying to use the exact same objects. When it's reused, your bindings are likely being overwritten.

Comment: Is this array defined in the XAML of the UserControl, or some other XAML somewhere (like Application.Resources)? If it's in the UserControl, I don't think my answer is correct. If it's elsewhere, try moving it to the UserControl.

Comment: Try adding x:Shared="False" to the array declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `x:Shared="False"` to the array declaration?

```
<x:Array x:Key="toolbarButtons" x:Shared="False" Type="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
```